# Add OnClickListener to Marker InfoWindow

Tags: android, kotlin, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is there a workaround for adding an OnClickListener to a marker's InfoWindow? I can add one to the marker itself. But I'm finding it more intuitive at a UI standpoint to tap the infowindow rather than the marker.

```
   addNewMarker = Marker(map, this).apply {
        position = (GeoPoint(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
        title = getString(R.string.add_new_spot)
        icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.add_new_marker)
        id = ADD_OBSERVATION_MARKER_ID.toString()
        showInfoWindow()
        setOnMarkerClickListener { marker, map -> intentToNewEntryActivity(latLng); true }
    }
        map.overlays.add(addObservationMarker)
```